# Formatting - conditional - vlookup- values from one cell to another different worksheets based on value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, vlookup

I would like to be able to enter a part# in column L of sheet 2 and a formula would look through column A of sheet 1 for a match, and then return their price from column F of sheet 1 into column K of sheet 2 same workbook. Please heeeeelp! Also, the part #'s in column A of sheet 1 will not necessarily be in the same row or of column l in sheet 2

Comment: You've mentioned `VLOOKUP` in the title, have you tried to use it yet?  If so, what did the formula look like?  This should be a standard application of `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: I didn't really try to use it but I was playing with it. It confuses me.

Comment: Ultimately that function is your answer.  Get a feel for it with dummy data on a single worksheet and then adapt it to your current data.  A good starting point is the Excel function reference (hit F1 in Excel to get help).  There is also the `INDEX-MATCH` pattern for doing this, but it is more complicated.  Check out these references if the built in help is not enough: http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions02.html, http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup/

Comment: I will try that. Thank you! Will it pull the content from a cell on one worksheet to the other or is that another formula?

Comment: I still can't get it to workout :( thank you any ways

Answer (score 0):

VLookup is what you need.

In cell K1 of sheet 2 of your book try the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(L1,Sheet1!A:F,6,FALSE)
```

This will look for the value in cell L1 on sheet 2 in column A of sheet 1 and when it finds it, it will return the value in the row and column F. Note that you may need to change the comma (,) for a semi-colon (;) depending on the region settings in excel.

This formula can be copied down the page and should work in all cells of column L.

Comment: I have another question of similar nature. Would you be able to help?